# XML parser is not working in robot framework

Tags: xml, robotframework

I am using xml parser to access element from response 
here is code

```
# define library 
*** Settings ***
Library  SudsLibrary
Library  XML
Library        Collections
*** Variables ***
*** Test Cases ***
test
    abc

*** Keywords ***
    # create soap client object 
    Create Soap Client    http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl
    ${GetCitiesByCountry}    Create Wsdl Object   GetCitiesByCountry
   ${GetCitiesByCountry.CountryName}    Set Variable    india
    # call soap web service 
    call soap method  GetCitiesByCountry  ${GetCitiesByCountry}
    log  ${GetCitiesByCountry}
    ${soap_response}    Get Last Received
    Log    ${soap_response}
    ${root}=   parse xml  ${soap_response}
    log  ${root}
    ${root1}=   parse xml  ${soap_response}  first
    log  ${root1}
```

Here is output : it does not show the resulting xml

```
Documentation:  
Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170626 11:52:46.886 / 20170626 11:52:46.886 / 00:00:00.000
11:52:46.886    INFO    <Element 'Envelope' at 0x0000000003670930
BuiltIn . Log ${root1}
Documentation:  
Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20170626 11:52:46.887 / 20170626 11:52:46.887 / 00:00:00.000
11:52:46.887    INFO    <Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x0000000003728C60>
```

Comment: The log statements you use isn't going to show the XML, because `${root}` and `${root1}` are objects, not strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the response of the webservice there is some strange things going on. It seems that part of it is HTML encoded, and the other isn't. Can't explain that, but it's easily solved with a simple string replacement.

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SudsLibrary
Library   XML
Library   String
*** Test Cases ***
Test Webservice
    # create soap client object 
    Create Soap Client    http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl

    ${GetCitiesByCountry}    Create Wsdl Object   GetCitiesByCountry
    ${GetCitiesByCountry.CountryName}    Set Variable    india

    # # call soap web service 
    call soap method  GetCitiesByCountry  ${GetCitiesByCountry}
    ${soap_response}    Get Last Received

    # Clean up response 
    ${soap_response}     Replace String    ${soap_response}    &lt;    <
    ${soap_response}     Replace String    ${soap_response}    &gt;    >    

    ${node}=   Get Element Text    ${soap_response}  .//Table[1]//Country[1]
    Log To Console    ${node}
```